# How to comment out a perticular line in all files in directory and sub directory using #ifdef and #endif?

Tags: linux

I want to insert #ifdef and #endif between a particular line .for eg -

```
FunctionXYZ(******);
```

should become

```
#ifdef X
FunctionXYZ(*****); //*****can be anything
#endif
```

in all files in directories and sub-directories .

Is there a linux command for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '/FUNCTIONXYZ/i NEWLINE' {} \; -> above


find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '/FUNCTIONXYZ/a NEWLINE' {} \; -> below
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do that... but my proposition assumes that this is for a project where you have several files in which you are using the function. So you may, in the definition of the function do something like

```
Functionxyz(****){
#ifdef X
      // do some coding
#endif
}
```

So if `X` is not defined, the function does nothing!
Note: I tried to put this as a comment but the formatting wasnt working out...

The edit follows the comment stating that you may not access the definition of the function.
So just use a wrapper function

```
myFunctionxyz(***){
#ifdef X
     FunctionXYZ(****)
 #endif
}
```

Comment: Functionxyz is outside my scope .. I can't modify it .

Answer (score 1):

> **This is generally a very dangerous operation since any mistake can break your entire system!**

But here you go:

```sh
# cat que

Something(else)
FunctionXYZ(junk);
blah blah
FunctionXYZ(junk2);

# find . -type f -exec grep -l "FunctionXYZ(" {} \;
./que

# cat que | sed -E "s/^(FunctionXYZ\()(.+)\);/\#ifdef X\n\1\2\); \/\/ \2\n\#endif\n/i"
Something(else)

#ifdef X
FunctionXYZ(junk); // junk
#endif

blah blah

#ifdef X
FunctionXYZ(junk2); // junk2
#endif
```

Put them together:

```
for x in `find . -type f -exec grep -l "FunctionXYZ(" {} \;`; do sed -i -E "s/^(FunctionXYZ\()(.+)\);/\#ifdef X\n\1\2\); \/\/ \2\n\#endif\n/i" $x; done;
```

Where:

- `-l, --files-with-matches` - print only names of FILEs containing matches
- `-type f` - only search for *regular* files
- `-E` - Use POSIX compliant *Extended* regular expressions
- `-i` - Use in-place file editing (**Dangerous!** - No backups!)

If your directory contain files that are large, this will take a very long time.

**Make a backup! And test in a separate sub-directory!!**